# Seq.map for a sequences inside a sequence

Tags: f#, functional-programming

While doing Code Abbey exercises I have lots of code like

```
seqOfSeqs
|> Seq.map (Seq.map Int32.Parse)
|> Seq.map (Seq.sum)
```

this seems ugly so the code blow comes to my mind

```
let actions seqs =
    seqs
    |> Seq.map Int32.Parse
    |> Seq.sum

seqOfSeq
|> Seq.map actions
```

What is the better solution to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be simpler:

```
seqOfSeqs|> Seq.map (Seq.sumBy System.Int32.Parse)
```

Comment: Could be even shorter using `int` instead of `Int32.Parse` : `seqOfSeqs |> Seq.map (Seq.sumBy int)`

Comment: @Sehnsucht yes, this would be more F#-ier